# When determinant of matrix of exponents is non-negative

Tags: determinant

This is problem I heard briefly, not even sure if it's well-stated, but here we are:

Prove that if $x_i>0, y_j>0$ then $\det e^{x_iy_j}\ge 0$.
I think there was also a hint to use "generalized Vandermonde determinant", but I can't figure out even what this generalized determinant is.

May be you have some ideas? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This property is erroneous : take the case of a $2 \times 2$ matrix with :

$$x_1=3, x_2=2 , y_1=1, y_2=2$$

The determinant of the matrix is

$$e^{x_1y_1}e^{x_2y_2}-e^{x_1y_2}e^{x_2y_1}$$

$$=e^{3}e^{4}-e^{6}e^{2}=e^{7}-e^{8} \color{red}{< 0}$$

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: Well, I see now, but... what was the task then?....

Comment: It cannot be the matrix with $M_{ij}=e^{x_i\color{red}{+}y_j}$ because this matrix has rank $1$ therefore with determinant always $0$.